# Xcode 6 beta 7 compiler error: swiftc failed with exit code 254

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, restkit

The full error is this:

> Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 254

I'm using RestKit to post an object to a json-accepting endpoint. The following works:

```
var manager = RKObjectManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: myURL))
manager.addRequestDescriptor(myItemRequestDescriptor)
manager.addResponseDescriptor(myItemResponseDescriptor)
manager.postObject(newItem, path: "/api/saveitem/", parameters: nil, success: nil , failure: nil)
```

But, if I want to do something with the resulting object:

```
manager.postObject(newItem, path: "/api/saveitem/", parameters: nil, success: { operation, result in dump(result) } , failure: { operation, error in dump(error) })
```

I get the error mentioned above. (Also, the line above causes SourceKitService to crash incessantly, I assume it's linked to SourceKitService failing to handle the compiler error gracefully.)

Here are some things that I've tried:

- Modifying the code line to use both types of closure syntax (named and unnamed closure parameters: `dump($1)`)
- Deleting the DerivedData folder

Has anyone experienced this? Have a workaround? Or have some ideas as to how to work around it?

***Edit: Wordaround 1***

Using the following to call the endpoint works without compiler errors. It's not an Xcode workaround, though, it's a RestKit workaround.

Instead of calling `manager.postObject()`, you can get an RKRequestOperation object and use that instead:

```
var operation: = manager.appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject(newItem, method: RKRequestMethod.POST, path: "/api/saveitem/", parameters: nil) as RKObjectRequestOperation
operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation, response) in
        dump(response)
    },
    failure: { (operation, error) in
        dump(error)
    })
operation.start()
```

Comment: Any compiler crashes **must be [reported](https://bugreport.apple.com/)**.

Comment: I did that. But I don't have two weeks to wait around for a fix. If I can't get anything to work, I'm going to start reverting Xcode builds a version at a time until I can get it to work.

Comment: That's what everybody does. ;)